# How can I add lots of rows to a DataTable quickly?

Tags: .net, performance, datatable

I'm adding >100,000 rows from a `DataRow[]` to a `DataTable`, and this is taking a significant amount of time (upwards of 1 second). Is there a way of quickly adding these rows to the table all at once?

EDIT:
I'm currently generating all the data in object arrays and using `table.Rows.Add(rowDataArray)`

Comment: How are you doing it right now? What have you tried?

Comment: @Tony: I'm using object arrays and `DataRowCollection.Add(object[])`

Answer (score 0):

if I remember well there are some methods to enable/disable validation on either datatable or dataset classes. I used in the past when loading a whole dataset from xml file and disabling validation before loading has improved loading times drastically. This might help.

Comment: @thecoop - out of interest, how much did that reduce the time by?

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge there is one bulk copy function available if you are talking about saving multiple records in database in one go.

Refer this link: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SqlBulkCopy.aspx[enter link description here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SqlBulkCopy.aspx)